# Erro de padding criptografia AES modo CBC com Pycrypto

Tags: python-3.x, criptografia, aes

Tenho o seguinte código funcionando perfeitamente:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

key = b'Sixteen byte key'
data = 'some text to encrypt'.encode("UTF-8")
data = pad(data, AES.block_size)
encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
iv = encryptor.IV
decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)

ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(data)
print(ciphertext)
plaintext = decryptor.decrypt(ciphertext)
print(unpad(plaintext, 16))
```

Mas ao tentar transformá-lo em uma função o resultado apresenta erro de padding. Código adaptado para uma função:

```
def cbc(msg, op):
    key = b'Sixteen byte key'
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
    iv = encryptor.IV
    decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
    if op == 1:
        data = msg.encode("UTF-8")
        data = pad(data, AES.block_size)
        ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(data)
        print(ciphertext)
    else:
        plaintext = decryptor.decrypt(msg)
        print(unpad(plaintext, 16))
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Google Drive/max/AES.py", line 48, in <module>
    cbc(b'*\xd3\xc1Y\xc2f;\xf0\xc0@\xd9E\xc5x\x11\xb4', 2)
  File "D:/Google Drive/max/AES.py", line 19, in cbc
    print(unpad(plaintext, 16))
  File "C:\Users\Evilmaax\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util\Padding.py", line 90, in unpad
    raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
ValueError: Padding is incorrect.
```

O erro aocntece no `else`, quando passo uma mensagem do tipo byte `*\xd3\xc1Y\xc2f;\xf0\xc0@\xd9E\xc5x\x11\xb4` por parâmetro. O mais estranho é que a mensagem foi gerada exatamente com o mesmo código, com o `if` anterior ao `else` em questão.

Alguém tem uma ideia do que pode estar ocorrendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quem interessar possa, segue o jeito como resolvi o problema com [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318120/cbc-mode-aes-encryption-problem-with-pycrypto).

Na minha função estava gerando um `iv` aleatório a cada execução, o que é bom, porém, não estava guardando esse `iv`. Assim, quando ia fazer a descriptação recorria a um novo `iv` aleatório; o que fazia o padding não bater.

A solução foi declarar um `iv` fixo tanto para criptografar como descriptografar.  Segue a organização do código após alteração:

```
iv = b'*\30a\xc1Y\xc2f;\9=1/\xc0@\xd9E\js38\x11\xb4'
def cbc(chave, msg, op):
if op == 1:
    cifra = AES.new(chave, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    msg = cifra.encrypt(msg)
    print(f"Mensagem cifrada: {msg}")
else:
    decifra = AES.new(chave, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
    print(f'Mensagem decifrada: {unpad(decifra.decrypt(msg), BLOCK_SIZE).decode("utf-8")}')
```

Comment: Usar um IV fixo é inseguro! Você precisa gerar uma IV aleatório e mandar junto com a mensagem. Também não deve usar somente cifração, e sim cifração autenticada, como o [GCM](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html)